# Welcome message send error if i join another guild with my bot already inside

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Im making a welcome message event for 1 guild only and i join the guild it sends the message all good but when i join another server with bot inside i get an error

Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘send’)

Code:

```
const { EmbedBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const { GuildMember, Embed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "guildMemberAdd",
    execute(member) {
        const { user, guild } = member;
        const welcomeChannel = member.guild.channels.cache.get("1012717996470452335");
      
      var role = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === "1012717995451236445");
      member.roles.add(role);

        const welcomeEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle("***New member!***")
        .setDescription(`Welcome <@${member.id}> to ***Zepp™ Support***`)
        .setColor(0xfffffe)
        .setTimestamp();

        welcomeChannel.send({ embeds: [welcomeEmbed] });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you join a server other than the one you want to send a message for the `member.guild.channels.cache.get()` method will not find the ID `"1012717996470452335"` (and therefore not return anything), so your `welcomeChannel` variable will be undefined.
You should only send the message if `welcomeChannel` has been set:

```js
...

if (welcomeChannel) {
    var role = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === "1012717995451236445");
    member.roles.add(role);

    const welcomeEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle("***New member!***")
        .setDescription(`Welcome <@${member.id}> to ***Zepp™ Support***`)
        .setColor(0xfffffe)
        .setTimestamp();

    welcomeChannel.send({ embeds: [welcomeEmbed] });
}
...
```